# How to generate conditional words in the text? (Inline code)

Tags: r-markdown

I want to have some conditional words in my R Markdown document. Depending of the outcome in some of the calculations from the tables different words should show up in the ordinary text. Please, see my example below:

The table (a chunk):

```
testtabell <- matrix(c(32, 33, 45, 67, 21, 56, 76, 33, 22), ncol=3,byrow = TRUE)
colnames(testtabell) <- c("1990", "1991", "1992")
rownames(testtabell) <- c("Region1", "Region2", "Region3")
testtabell <- as.table(testtabell)
testtabell
```

This should be in the inline code and generate different word options in the regular text flow in the RMD:

```
`r if testtabell[2,2]-[2,1] < testtabell[3,2]-testtabell[3,1] then type "under" or else "above"`
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is ancient, maybe someone can use this solution.

You can use the following inline code:

```
`r ifelse(testtabell[2,2]-testtabell[2,1] < testtabell[3,2]-testtabell[3,1],"under","above")`
```